# Prevents bots, and stay in current URL if User is real

Tags: php

I have a script on my website, to prevents bots, it works fine but since i modified it to make changes i had a lot of errors, i'm not good at php.

```html
<?php 
error_reporting();
session_start();

$config_antibot['apikey']   = '________________________';
$config_antibot['bot']      = 'https://google.com';
$config_antibot['real']     = 'https://mywebsite.com';

class Antibot
{
    function apikey($api_key){
        $this->apikey = $api_key;
    }
    function get_client_ip()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
                  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
                  $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
        }
        $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    
        if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $client;
        }
        elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $forward;
        }
        else
        {
            $ip = $remote;
        }
    
        return $ip;
    }
    function httpGet($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        return $response;
    }
    function check(){
        $ip         = $this->get_client_ip();
        $respons    = $this->httpGet("https://antibot.pw/api/v2-blockers?ip=".$ip."&apikey=".$this->apikey."&ua=".urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
        $json       = json_decode($respons,true);
        if($json['is_bot'] == 1 || $json['is_bot'] == true){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
$Antibot = new Antibot;
$Antibot->apikey( $config_antibot['apikey'] );
if($Antibot->check() == true){
    die(header("location: ".$config_antibot['bot']));
}else{
    die(header("location: ".$config_antibot['real']));
}
?>
```

The lines that i tried to change

Line 7

```
$config_antibot['real']     = 'https://mywebsite.com';
```

Line 63

```
die(header("location: ".$config_antibot['real']));
```

Line 7 If the visitor is real not a bot it redirected to my website, but this redirect is causing a problem and affecting the nature of my website

Because when users sign up and get link [mywebsite.com/user/02331/index?ref=02331](https://mywebsite.com/user/02331/index?ref=02331) via email to activate their account, the user is redirected to [mywebsite.com](https://mywebsite.com) the user cannot not check [mywebsite.com/user/02331/index?ref=02331](https://mywebsite.com/user/02331/index?ref=02331) to complete registration

i change in line 63 to

```
  die( header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized") );
exit();
```

}

But that doesn't seem to work for me, is there a way to let the user stay on the current url that the user is browsing if the user is real and not a bot?

Comment: Use .htaccess and block bots based on user-agent, not ip. Check your server logs and you will see all traffic.

Comment: @Jakub Muda htaccess dont do the job as well as the bot joined my website, this script work fine but the only thing i dont like is that redirecting when user is real

Comment: Your does a request to `antibot.pw` on each request of a user? This is bad, real bad. It slows down your site, your site will throw errors when antibot.pw is down, etc... The only thing i can suggest here, re-think your whole idea of this antibot.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to create is a middleware (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware for laravel), or chain of responsibility (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). Depending on how you have it structured at the moment, this could mean you need to change the entire architecture of your code, which obviously isn't a great solution.

Ideally, you would have a router or some such that you can call here:

```
}else{
    Route::get( ... );
    // die(header("location: ".$config_antibot['real']));
}
```

You don't need to die() into the next portion of your site, you just need the page that they want to load to appear instead of the redirect. This could be done in any number of ways, but the `die()` portion is probably the least best option of them.